# Do we want both and "overlay" and an "overlays" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I just saw that we have 2 (now 3) questions tagged [overlays](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overlays) and 8 tagged [overlay](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overlay). Is this by intention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it should only be [overlays](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overlays).

Comment: So should they be merged (or whatever the correct expression for this is)?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. But only a mod can do this.

Comment: I've used the 'mod hammer' to sort this out :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Joseph. Just found your comment while checking back if something happened `:-)`